# Identifier is expected || Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs

I am getting an error when I run this code:

> Unexpected token

And also is VS code it is showing as:

> identifier expected

In VS code inside the for loop where we provide `i < this.state.counter;` in the semi colon red color error is highlighted when we hover on it. It shows a message as identifier expected:

```js
class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            counter: 0
        }
    }

    handleOnclick = () => {
        this.setState({
            counter: this.state.counter+1
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <h3>The counter is at {this.state.counter}</h3>
                <button onClick= {this.handleOnclick}>Click</button>
                for (let i = 0; i < this.state.counter; i++){
                    <div>Line</div>
                }
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For-loops aren't valid in JSX and you've not properly enclosed the Javascript in a `{}` block. The error is implying that it thinks `this.state.counter` is the start of an HTML element tag.

Create an array and map it to JSX.

```
<Fragment>
  <h3>The counter is at {this.state.counter}</h3>
  <button onClick= {this.handleOnclick}>Click</button>
  {[...Array(this.state.counter).keys()].map(el => (
    <div key={el}>Line</div>
  )}
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Thanks mate the above solution made the thing work for me but could you tell the reason behind spreading the Array and passing the state inside it and what is this technique called.

Comment: @SouravThakur It's just a quick/simple way to generate an array with increasing values (`[0,1,2,3,4,....]`). TBH I don't know if this pattern has a name, it's just something picked up over time. Another snippet you may see is something like `Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i)` to generate `[0,1,2,....,7,8,9]`.